# AspectJ - Change implementation package

Tags: java, aspectj

We have an existing java library code using [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/), we want to be able to use our library on Android without maintaining 2 versions of the code.

Using Bouncy Castle on Android is always complicated and one of the common solution is to use [Spongy Castle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/), which is a simple repackaging of Bouncy Castle (same classes with same signatures but in a different package and without hierarchical relationship between the 2 packages).

My question is whether it is possible to use AspectJ on our existing library to replace Bouncy Castle by Spongy Castle ?

I know that AspectJ is not necessarily intended for this task but as we are already using it, it would be nice to be able to integrate this implementation switch with the others aspects. If it's not possible, do you know another way (tool) to do it ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to change the imports at runtime?

Comment: It's not possible to use AspectJ at runtime on Android, but we can "patch" the jar using AspectJ before including it in the android project.